# EAS BUILD com.segment.analytics.android:analytics error while submitting my app to Google Play Console

Tags: android, react-native, eas

Using `eas build -p android` but still have this error

The error message says:
Your app version code 14 includes SDK com.segment.analytics.android:analytics or an SDK that one of your libraries depends on, which collects personal or sensitive data that includes but may not be limited to Advertising ID, Android ID identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers as described in the User Data policy.

my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.0.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@types/hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "d3": "^7.8.4",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.1.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-device": "^5.2.1",
    "expo-linking": "^4.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-network": "^5.2.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-store-review": "^6.2.1",
    "expo-task-manager": "~11.1.1",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.30",
    "luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1297.0",
    "react-native-component-inview": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.13",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^15.0.1",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.6",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-swipe-out": "^2.0.14",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-debounced": "^0.5.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
```

I am not using com.segment.analytics.android:analytics and I have looked inside my node_modile and I don't see any package using 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics' so I am really confused now

I also tried `expo install expo-analytics-segment`so that the latest version is there but still does not fix the problem